# Getting a NullPointerException when browsing the DXA 1.4 Java web site in Tomcat

Tags: dxa

I've deployed the Java DXA 1.4 web app in Tomcat. My publication is fully published to the broker database.
When I browse to the site I get the following error. Any ideas what could be causing it?

> 10:26:12.130 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] TRACE c.s.w.c.i.i.LocalizationResolverInterceptor - Localization for http://localhost:8080/about/contact is: [5] /
>   10:26:12.130 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] TRACE c.s.w.c.i.i.StaticContentInterceptor - preHandle: /about/contact
>   10:26:12.130 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] TRACE c.s.w.c.controller.PageController - handleGetPage: requestPath=/about/contact
>   10:26:12.130 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] DEBUG c.s.w.t.m.AbstractDefaultProvider - Try to find page: [5] /about/contact.html
>   10:26:12.136 [http-apr-8080-exec-4] ERROR c.s.w.c.controller.PageController - Exception while processing request for: /about/contact
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.ModelBuilderPipeline.createPageModel(ModelBuilderPipeline.java:71) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.AbstractDefaultProvider$1.tryFindPage(AbstractDefaultProvider.java:287) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.AbstractDefaultProvider$1.tryFindPage(AbstractDefaultProvider.java:267) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.AbstractDefaultProvider.findPage(AbstractDefaultProvider.java:102) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.AbstractDefaultProvider.getPageModel(AbstractDefaultProvider.java:267) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.getPageModel(PageController.java:321) ~[dxa-common-api-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.handleGetPage(PageController.java:129) ~[dxa-common-api-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219) ~[spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:604) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:565) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624) [servlet-api.jar:na]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) [servlet-api.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.62]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
>       at com.sdl.web.preview.filter.ContentFilter.doFilter(ContentFilter.java:122) [cd_preview_content_common-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
>       at com.sdl.web.preview.filter.ContentFilter.doFilter(ContentFilter.java:122) [cd_preview_content_common-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
>       at com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter.java:286) [web-ambient-client-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423) [catalina.jar:7.0.62]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.62]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.62]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2476) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.62]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2465) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.62]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.62]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]

Comment: Have you implemented any custom `PageBuilder`? If not, then most probably the problem is occurring because DD4T returns a `null` from `dd4tPageFactory` which is actually strange, and, following the code analyze, shows a probable problem with caching. Did you modify default cache settings? Stop at breakpoint at `ModelBuilderPipeline:71` and check what's `null`: `pageBuilder` or `genericPage`.

Comment: Hi, I've not modified any cache settings.     I'm not able to stop the pocess at a breakpoint. I'm not familiar with such things.

Comment: For the caching, are you referring to the cache channel service? In the session microservice (which I assume the webapp is using) the storage conf file has " <ObjectCache Enabled="false">" and so the cache service is not in use. Or are you referrring to some other form of caching?

Comment: Oh, and "no" to a custom pagebuilder.

Answer (score 1):

There were so many issues getting DXA working but most related to my microservices set-up, not to the DXA webapp. I think this one was cured by moving to Tomcat 8.5 at Alexey Zarakovskiy's suggestion. I'd been on Tomcat 7. The pre-requisites could need updating.